# Attempting to install OAuth on Ubuntu but getting errors

Tags: php, ubuntu, oauth

I am attempting to install OAuth on Ubuntu Server 12.04 but getting errors. I am following this tutorial but something isn't lining up:

http://sergiopvilar.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/how-to-install-php-oauth-extension/

Command I am running in terminal:

```
sudo pecl install oauth
```

Last portion of error I am getting response (because it returns several pages of response):

```
    running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootFgGDRe/oauth-1.2.3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oauth -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootFgGDRe/oauth-1.2.3/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootFgGDRe/oauth-1.2.3/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oauth -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2 -Wall -g   -c /tmp/pear/temp/oauth/oauth.c -o oauth.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oauth -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootFgGDRe/oauth-1.2.3/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootFgGDRe/oauth-1.2.3/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oauth -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -Wall -g -c /tmp/pear/temp/oauth/oauth.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oauth.o
In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/oauth/php_oauth.h:47:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/oauth/oauth.c:14:
/usr/include/php5/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [oauth.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Make is installed and working. Any advice?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found it, I needed to install PCRE Library ( Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library ).

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks...Worked for me

Comment: Thanks! Helped me install the mongodb extension

Comment: It should be noted that if you are running CentOS, the package names are different, you'll need to run `yum install pcre.i686` or `yum install pcre.x86_64` depending on whether you have 32-bit or 64-bit. However, on my machine, this doesn't appear to be the cause of the same `make: *** [oauth.lo] Error 1` problem, as it tells me `Package pcre-7.8-7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version`.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev
sudo pecl install mongodb
```