# Missing PHP includes (.h)

Tags: php, mongodb, header-files, php-extension

I am trying to install a PHP extension mongodb for non-default php binary location. I am using PECL:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

and after long logs  I get this

```
/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/bson.c:29:17: fatal error: php.h: No such file or directory
 #include <php.h>
          ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:338: recipe for target 'src/bson.lo' failed
make: *** [src/bson.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

How can I get rid of this?

- OS: Ubuntu 15.10
- PHP Version: 5.6.10
- /usr/include has no php.h
- /usr/include/php5/include has no files
- I have installed PHP via apt-get
- I have installed and reinstalled php5-dev package

Comment: What happens when you try to install it manually?

Comment: It compiling, but not working. I have an error:

Comment: `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './mongodb.so' - ./mongodb.so: undefined symbol: file_globals in Unknown on line 0
`

Comment: did you phpize? this basically says you compiled against a version of php different than the one you're running against. You might want to clean these up.

Comment: yes, I tried phpize different of different versions, including 5.6.10 and bundled in the php standalone build

Comment: You need to make sure you're building against the php you are trying to load the ext into

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same solution as here: [Attempting to install OAuth on Ubuntu but getting errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772854/attempting-to-install-oauth-on-ubuntu-but-getting-errors)

Install the PCRE Library (Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library) with:

```
# sudo apt-get update
# sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev
```